# Use imported java library

Tags: java, encryption, crypt

I have imported this library http://raginggoblin.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/java-alternative-to-php-crypt-function/, in to my project but yet unable to use the class named "crypt" to encrypt string by passing **password** and **salt** to crypt method in it.

```
public class JavaApplication6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
           String password = "rasmuslerdorf";
           String salt = "$6$rounds=5000$usesomesillystringforsalt$";
           String encrypted = Crypt.crypt(password, salt);

            System.out.println(""+encrypted);
        }
}
```

this is the imported library contains,

[image]

Comment: Not getting the correct method I guess! Try giving the absolute path:-
String encrypted = raging.goblin.crypt.Crypt.crypt(password, salt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted code, I suspect you aren't getting the correct `Crypt`. I suggest you use a [`static import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) and change this,

```
String encrypted = Crypt.crypt(password, salt);
```

to

```
String encrypted = crypt(password, salt);
```

or you might use,

```
String encrypted = raging.goblin.crypt.Crypt.crypt(password, salt);
```

And  the `static import` would be,

```
static import raging.goblin.crypt.Crypt.crypt;
```

Finally your image tells me you got the src jar, the way you're using it you want the binary jar.